# Understanding WS-Security and XML-Enc parts of a SOAP Request

Tags: xml, nist

I'm attempting to build a SOAP client to consume the services provided by [eMedNy](https://www.emedny.org/). They've provided me with a client **X.509** certificate along with their server **X.509** certificate.

Their [user guide](https://www.emedny.org/selfhelp/SOAP/eMedNY_Meds_History_Service_User_Guide_1.1.pdf) contains the following sample SOAP request:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mhs="http://org/emedny/mhs/" xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d">MIICeDCC....(eMedNY signed user MLS cert).......</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685">MIIDFj.....( eMedNY MLS web-service end-point public cert)........</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-970e9a80-00cc-4c86-8ec4-3ba16e029a5b">
        <wsse:Username>....your_username.....</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">.....your_plaintext_password....</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>KNyu6MsXCkTg4DDyvwvEiw==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2010-09-15T18:00:30Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
      <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
          <xenc:CipherValue>gpBAWt91pdwhKva............</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:ReferenceList>
          <xenc:DataReference URI="#Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794"/>
        </xenc:ReferenceList>
      </xenc:EncryptedKey>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="#Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>wRUq.........</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>tBSsaZi........</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <xenc:EncryptedData Id="Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
      <xenc:CipherData>
        <xenc:CipherValue>SQsTCAK6ZaVhojB8+Y.........</xenc:CipherValue>
      </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I just wanted to verify the following two points to make sure my understanding is accurate:

1. The SOAP body gets encrypted using the eMedNy server certificate using **TRIPLE-DES**.   We then encrypt this server certificate using **RSA** and send it as a message header.
2. To generate the digital signature, we take the **TRIPLE-DES** encrypted message body and obtain a **SHA-1** digest. Using the eMedNy-supplied X.509 client certificate,  we encrypt the digest which gives us the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client proceeds as follows (I am considering only the encryption and signature steps as these are relevant for you):

1) Encryption:

- It generates a fresh 3DES symmetric key
- It encrypts the newly generated symmetric key with the public key of the server (using the RSA-PKCS1 algorithm, see EncryptionMethod algorithm) and places it into the EncryptedKey/CipherData/CipherValue element.
- The public key used for encryption is referenced using the EncryptedKey/KeyInfo/SecurityTokenReference/Reference element. There we can see that the public key from certificate wsu:Id="Sec...1685" was used. Once the server accepts the message it knows that it should use the corresponding private key for decryption.
- The generated symmetric key is used for SOAP Body encryption, with a 3DES-CBC algorithm.

2) Signature:

- The client computes a SHA-1 digest over the whole SOAP Body. You can see this since the Reference element references an element with wsu:Id="Id...05b", which belongs to the SOAP Body. The digest value is then placed into Signature/SignedInfo/Reference/DigestValue.
- The client uses its private key and computes an RSA-SHA1 signature over the SignedInfo element. The signature value is then placed into the SignatureValue element.
- In order to validate the signature, the server needs to know the client's public key. For this purpose, the client places its certificate into the message and references it in Signature/KeyInfo/SecurityTokenReference/Reference. Once the server accepts the message, it knows that it has to use a certificate with wsu:Id="Security...bb3d" to get the public key and verify the signature.

Comment: Yes, this is correct; by now I've figured it out..